# Strange behaviour of Visual Studio while trying to make windows installer package

Tags: visual-studio, setup-project

I have serious problem with Visual Studio, I'm trying to create Windows Installer package, so i have created new setup project, but the "Add Project Output Group" function doesn't work. The drop-down lists are empty, so i can't do absolutely nothing. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Do you have any other projects in the solution? What do you expect to be in the drop-down lists?

Answer (score 3):

Did you add the setup project to an existing solution that already contained a WinForms project, or did you just create a new setup project?  The difference here is between clicking "FILE | NEW | PROJECT" or clicking "FILE | ADD | NEW PROJECT" (you want the latter).

Comment: Yeah, i used the first option initially, that's why it wasn't working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

But now i can't add the folders and data files needed for the application. I create the appropriate folders in the 'application folder', then add files into the appropriate folders, and when i install the application and go to the installation folder there are no folders...there is only the application exe file, hm...